# scrollmagic anchoring or pausing animation until user scrolls again

Tags: gsap, scrollmagic

with the following code,

```
var firstScene = new TimelineLite() 
    .to(".some-background", 1000, { transform: 'translate(350px, 0)' })
    .to(".old-text", 1000, { opacity: 0 })
    .to(".new-text", 1000, { opacity: 1 })
    .to(".new-text", 1000, { opacity: 0 })
    .to(".new-text-2", 1000, { opacity: 1 })

new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerHook: 'onLeave', triggerElement: "#container", duration: 5000})
    .setPin("#container")
    .setTween(firstScene)
    .addTo(controller);
```

is it possible to 'anchor' or stop/pause the animation between fading in .new-text and fading it out until user scrolls again rather than creating another trigger somewhere to just delay the animation?